# Logical help needed for if condition

Tags: c++

I have 3 varibles holding values Day Of Week(enum of week), Hour(0 to 23) and Minute(0 to 23), These 3 variables can hold only one common value N/A and other values are different.
If all are N/A or some valid values then I have to execute a particular logic A. If anyone is NA and others are valid then I have to execute some other Logic B

I tryed a lot using an `if` statement, without being able to come up with the right solution. Can some one give me a hint?

All values are integers

```
bool weeklyCount = (dayofweek == weeklyHour) && (weeklyHour == weeklyMinute);
```

This didn't work for me.

Comment: "I tryed a lot" what did you try?

Comment: Are these variables strings?  Could you edit your post to include the code you have already tried?

Comment: c++ only
Tried with different combination in if, but not getting the corret logic

Comment: Some problems: (1) It's now 08:42 per my clock. Note that the minutes, 42, is not between 0 and 23. (2) What if the time is 5 minutes after 5 on the fifth day of the week?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudocode:

```
if (dow == NA && hour == NA && minute == NA ||
    dow != NA && hour != NA && minute != NA) {
   // logic A
} else {
   // logic B
}
```

Comment: Here only checking for NA not any other valid values, My case if ony one is NA then I have to execute logic B. Here elseif exit when anyone is NA and wilnot check others as it is a or condition

Comment: @Sijith: The check for valid values is implicit (assuming each variable contains either NA or a valid value).

Answer (score 0):

```
struct yourtime
{
    enum Day
    {
        INVALID = -1,
        SUNDAY,
        MONDAY,
        TUESDAY,
        WEDNESDAY,
        THURSDAY,
        FRIDAY,
        SATURDAY
    };
    Day day;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    yourtime() : day(INVALID), hour(INVALID), minute(INVALID) { }
    bool isValid()
    {
        return (day != INVALID) && (hour != INVALID) && (minute != INVALID);
    }
};

int main()
{
    yourtime test;
    std::cout << test.isValid() << std::endl;
}
```

Take advantage of the fact that enums are the same size as ints.